# Strong convergence of a sequence in $B(X,Y)$, where $X$ is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces, where $X$ is Banach.

Let $(T_n)_n$ be a sequence in $B(X,Y)$ such that for each $x\in X$, $T_n(x)$ converges in norm to some $T(x)\in Y$.

Show $T \in B(X,Y)$.

I showed that $T$ is linear. Now I have to show that it's bounded.

I know that there exists some $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, $\| T_n(x) - T(x)\| < \epsilon$.

Also, by the principle of uniform boundedness, we know that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we can find a constant $M_n$ such that $\| T_n(x)\| \leq M_n \| x\|$.

Now I'm not sure how to finish this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unifrom Boundeness Principle tells you that there exists one constant $M$ (independent of $n$) such that $\|T_nx\| \leq M\|x||$ for all $x$ and all $n$. Letting $n \to \infty$ in this we get $\|Tx\| \leq M\|x||$ for all $x$.